# Restore capability (plugin?) for NetBeans 6.9.1 after crash?

Tags: netbeans, crash, restore, autosave, netbeans-6.9

NetBeans 6.9.1 is the first version I've used that is only mostly stable (x86-64 Linux box).  I find that I am missing the "restore" features found in word processors and web browsers--upon a crash, you only lose a small amount of unsaved work.  Is there anything like this available for NetBeans?

These are workarounds that I do not consider solutions:

- Autosave open files without reversion to the most-recently-manually-saved version.  Since I lose my undo history, I want my unedited file as well as the edited one.
- Version control + autosave.  I know how to set this up, and it's a hassle, since I would need to have the files under dual version control (the "real" one and the "NetBeans crashes on me" one).
- Use an older version of NetBeans that crashes so rarely that this isn't an issue.  I require plugins that only work with 6.9.1.